# Angular Table with Editing

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to make a quick little data-grid directive with editing for a project. Here's the code sans directive.

HTML

```
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <table class=pure-table pure-table-striped>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in data">
        <td ng-repeat="col in row"><input ng-model="col"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p>{{data}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {  
  $scope.data = [
    [100, 200, 300],
    [400, 500, 600]
  ];
});
```

CSS

```
td input { border: none; text-align: right; width: 5em; }
```

And the codepen: http://codepen.io/mikeward/pen/gwcjt

This "almost" works except the data model never gets updated even though I'm using two-way binding (it's behaving as one-way at the moment). Is this an Angular bug or am I just not understanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write `ng-model="row[$index]"` instead of `ng-model="col"`.

I'm not sure about the reason, but this appears similar to likewise problems with Forms and Inputs. I believe that the input creates a child scope. `col` is just a scalar variable, so when the scope is copied, the `col` in the copy ends up being a totally separate variable. Changes to the copy of `col` will thus not change the original. `row` on the other hand is a non-scalar variable and this gets "copied" by "reference", therefore any changes to `row` in the input will also change the original `row`.

The AngularJS people stress that having a scalar variable in `ng-model` is doing it wrong. They advise that there shall be a dot in the `ng-model`. `row[$index]` does not contain a dot but is basically just `row.$index` with `$index` interpolated first.

Comment: Well that works better but the focus leaves the control after typing one character in any of the input controls.

Comment: Yes, but this probably can't be changed without adding much more copy and copying the data before it is edited. You are changing the data, so the ng-repeat will run again. Maybe http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ will help you?